# CURL Infer Request to HTTP Headers?

Tags: ios, swift, http, curl, grpc

I was given a manual for the server-client model I should implement for my app, but I don't know how to convert this into HTTP request format.

```
$curl -X POST <endpoint>
-H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"
-H 'InferRequest: batch_size: 1 input { name: "input" } output { name: "InceptionV3/Predictions/Softmax" cls { count: 1 } }'
-—data-binary "<filepath>"
```

This is the original curl command, and my swift code is the following.

```
class APIManager {
    
    static private let apiKey = "fill in key" // paste in Key(Token)
    static private let apiUrl = "fill in url" // paste in URL

    func postData(image: UIImage) {
        
        let urlString = APIManager.apiUrl

        let url = URL(string: urlString)

        guard url != nil else {

            print("URL nil")
            return
        }

        // header
        let token = "Bearer \(APIManager.apiKey)"

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 1)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        urlRequest.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        urlRequest.addValue("batch_size: 1 input { name: \"input\" } output { name: \"Darknet\" cls { count: 1 } }", forHTTPHeaderField: "InferRequest") // "input", "output" field should differ when we plug in Darknet
        
        // body
        let imageData = image.pngData()
        
        urlRequest.httpBody = imageData?.base64EncodedData()
        
        // handle the request
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

This part is where I am having trouble with.

```
urlRequest.addValue("batch_size: 1 input { name: \"input\" } output { name: \"Darknet\" cls { count: 1 } }", forHTTPHeaderField: "InferRequest")
```

Can I just stick the whole value in like this and treat it as a string?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, `String` is the only option that I know of to pass a header field in a `URLRequest`. Did it worked?

Comment: @gcharita Nah, I decided to take a break and restart from tomorrow. I'll tell you if I get any meaningful results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Here is what you can do if you want the code outOfThe Curl

Step 1 : Open Postman

Step 2 : Click on import (Left top Corner / Cmd + O)

Step 3 : Click on Raw Text

Step 4 : Paste Your curl

Step 5 : Click on Continue and Then Import

Step 6 : Click on the imported Request

Step 7 : Under the Send Button You will find Button named code. Clicking on will show you a window where you can get the code for swift